# How to cause execution of a class method when ever another class method has been called

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a  image pre-processing class in python.

for debug purposes I have interest to run a debug method on every  call to one of the class method which would save/show the input and output image based on parameters specified in the method call or in  the signature of the init method.

is there a  way to make such function get executed without the need to call in the implementation of every new method?

at the moment I have written a Show method and I an calling it on every method of my class. I am soon to write a similar save-file method

```
def Show(self, image, viewOutput=True, title=None):
    if self.BOOL_StepByStepViewOutput or viewOutput:
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
        plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
        if title:
            plt.title(title)
        plt.show() 

def ExamplePreprocessingFunction (self , InputImage  , BoolViewOutput , BoolViewInput): 
    self.show(InputImage , BoolViewInput , 'Input Image ,      ExamplePreprocessingFunction') 
    OutputImage=#Do some pre-processing staff   
    self.show (OutputImage , BoolViewOutput , 'Output Image Pre-Processing Function')
```

I would like to have a function which will automatically show or not show save or not save the Input and  the output image based on parameters specified to via the init method or better via the pre-processing method to be executed. 
In all implementations I am not over ridding the Input Image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good use case for a decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def log_this(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.log('Before calling', func.__name__)
        r_value = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.log('After calling', func.__name__)
        return r_value
    return inner

class Foo:
    @log_this
    def bar(self):
        print('in bar')

    def log(self, *args):
        print(*args)

f = Foo()
f.bar()
```

Outputs

```
Before calling bar
in bar
After calling bar
```